# How to split a string containing digits and characters

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a long string (containing digits and characters in it without any space) in to different substrings in Python?

```
>>> s = "abc123cde4567"
```

after split will get

```
['abc', '123', 'cde', '4567']
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include your attempt at solving the problem so we can show you went wrong. Otherwise, you may be downvoted and/or the question closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[a-z]+|[0-9]+", "abc123cde4567")
['abc', '123', 'cde', '4567']
```

Answer (score 1):

Something different from a regex:

```
from itertools import groupby
from string import digits

s = "abc123cde4567"
print [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, digits.__contains__)]
# ['abc', '123', 'cde', '4567']
```